# php-- $variable = [] error

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting an error when I try to set an array using

```
$var = []; // throws error
$var = array(); // no error
```

The error is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

Never seen this before! I assume it's a quirk in a version of PHP? It's also throwing the same error when I do something like:

```
$var[] = $newvalue;
```

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I've never initialised an array with `$var = [];` but always with `$var = array();`  but maybe that's just me

Comment: Really? It always use [], but never for my answers on SO because it'll lead to people commenting -- oh syntax error.

Comment: never even seen any one do that, oh well learn something new  every day

Comment: I guess I've just been using PHP 5.4 for so long I got used to it.

Comment: @user101289 That must be it. However I would recommend you to use the second way. Indeed it is really rare to initialize array the way you do it. Hope it helped!

Comment: @AdamSinclair It's probably only "really rare" because so many PHP programmers have a history in PHP 5.3, 5.0, or even 4.x. What's the point in the new syntax existing if we discourage everyone from ever adopting it?

Comment: @IMSop You are right. But it is just a personal preference. I would rather use a syntax that a majority of users adopt than a new syntax that is not well known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$var = [];` is legal as of PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a "quirk in a version", but it does require a minimum version: the "short array syntax" (`[]` as a synonym for `array()`) was introduced in PHP 5.4, as can be seen [from the release notes of that version](http://php.net/releases/5_4_0.php).

You can also check which versions of PHP a piece of code will work in using the online tool  at http://3v4l.org, which runs a snippet of code in a wide variety of builds, from PHP 4 to what will eventually be PHP 7, and even various versions of HHVM. [Here is an example of running this code](http://3v4l.org/sQBif).